# How to measure the difference between the trend of two curves

Tags: equities, finance, finance-mathematics

I'm looking for a way to measure the trend of two curves. For example, the figure below is my forecast for the S&P 500. It can be seen that although I haven't predicted the exact index price, the trends of the two curves are quite the same, including the rising and falling time and the turning point time. I have tried distances like DTW and Frechet, but the results are not very good. So is there a way to measure this?
[image]

Thank for your help!!

Comment: Generally it’s easier to predict returns than prices. In any case, why are the results of DTW and Fréchet not good?

Comment: Uh.., the result of DTW and Frechet feedback will be a curve entangled with the true value. I think it seems that although the two curves have similar trends, the distance between them is too large.

Comment: In addition, I hope that the predicted inflection point will be very close to the true value, but DTW will not consider this point.

Comment: @BobJansen, there is a one-to-one relationship between returns and prices, so one cannot be easier to predict than the other.

Comment: s/predict/easier to work with